# Any purpose of using a LoadableDetachableModel in a DataProvider?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

Since it is still not 100% clear when a LDM should be used I tried a simple memory test.
I created a DataView with a DataProvider that simply creates a list of few 100 entities with some big data inside (long String):

```
    private class HeavyDataProvider implements IDataProvider<HeavyBean> {

    @Override
    public void detach() {
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends HeavyBean> iterator(int first, int count) {
        List<HeavyBean> l = newArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            l.add(new HeavyBean());
        }
        return l.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<HeavyBean> model(HeavyBean heavyBean) {
        return new CompoundPropertyModel<HeavyBean>(heavyBean);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Using wicket's DebugBar is see this creates a Page with a size of 5MB. In the javadoc of DataProvider it is stated that the model return in above model method is *usually a detachable one* so I changed this method to:

```
        @Override
    public IModel<HeavyBean> model(final HeavyBean heavyBean) {
        return new LoadableDetachableModel<HeavyBean>() {

            @Override
            protected HeavyBean load() {
                return heavyBean;
            }
        };
    }
```

Naively I was expecting the pagesize to be reduced in a big way now since the heavybeans will no longer be part of the model. Actual result: 5MB. Since the model will detach the heavyBean this must mean that something else still has a hold of it (DataView? Item?).

I saw other examples where DataView and DataProvider are combined in a similar fashion but for me it is unclear what the point is since it does not seem to make any difference regarding the pageSize/memory usage.

So, am I understanding/doing something wrong (likely) or are LDM's useless in DataProviders?
Side question (sorry), in which scenario would you use an LDM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of LDM is just plain wrong. It is holding a direct reference to the bean itself, and just returning it. This way, the bean will be serialized along the model, making it completely pointless.

You should do something like this:

```
@Override
public IModel<HeavyBean> model(final HeavyBean heavyBean) {
    final Integer id = heavyBean.getId();
    return new LoadableDetachableModel<HeavyBean>() {
        @Override
        protected HeavyBean load() {
            return ServiceLocator.get(HeavyDao.class).get(id);
        }
    };
}
```

If you use the `wicket-ioc` module, the `HeavyDao` reference could be injected into the enclosing page/component.

I think Wicket is really easy to use, but you must understand the basics of Java serialization, or else you may end up with a very bloated http session.

Comment: Hm, I must have done something wrong during my tests. Yesterday I tried to simply return a new HeavyBean() in the load method, so not holding on to the original HeavyBean, but this made no difference to the results. If I retry it now the results make more sense: 43,5KB.

Comment: In this scenario wouldn't you pass the instance of HeavyBean to the LDM when you create it?

Comment: If you pass a heavyBean reference to the LDM, it will end up being serialized along the page, killing the very purpose of using a LDM in the first place.

Comment: I don't think so but correct me if I'm wrong: the object that you pass to the constructor of an LDM is stored inside the LDM as transient variable and is set to null when detach() is called. Also, it wouldn't make much sense to load your entities just to get the id and never ever use the entities loaded by the DataProvider.

Comment: If you use Hibernate with the open-session-in-view pattern, the `get(id)` call would reuse the session cache instance, so you won't hit the database again. But indeed, if you pass the instance to the constructor, the model will reuse this instance, and the `load()` method won't be called in this request.

Comment: Thanks, we don't use this pattern (I'm the sort off developer that believes no one should :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

For the LDM to work, you will have to actually detach the data in the detach() method. LDMs are meant to be used with databases, where you can restore / load the data on the next request with only the knowledge of an ID. So, in detach() you would trow away all data but the ID (or watever you need to relaod the data when needed) and in the load() (is this right? can't lock up the api right now) you will restore the data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tx, isn't LDM supposed to handle the detaching? I know you can override onDetach but I don't see what else could be done here that isn't already done in LDM.detach()?